# Hibernate second level caching of entities getting repeated attribute values for all entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

I have a classical entity for countries which is totally immutable and small so I decided to cache the entities with hibernate, but if I enable the entity caching when I query for all the entities I got the other attributes apart from the id repeated (i.e. a list with different ids but same name and also same value for all the other fields).

```
@Immutable
@Entity @Table(name="countries")
@Cacheable @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Country {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Short id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    ....
}
```

The hibernate configuration is as follows:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=data-catalogs-create.sql,data-mysql-sample.sql
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=com.example.util.ImplicitNamingStrategy
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=com.example.util.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.redis.hibernate5.SingletonRedisRegionFactory
hibernate.cache.region_prefix=hibernate
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path=hibernate-redis.properties
hibernate.generate_statistics=false
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/var/lucene/indexes
```

The equals/hashCode is based on the entity id and I have tests on it (the guava tests), so I discarded some error related to that.

On the moment I remove/comment the @Cacheable/@Cache annotation the problem disappear.